# Perl Outlook web access

Tags: perl, outlook-web-app

My PC has internet access but no access to a mail server due to security reason (don't ask ;)). I have to send several mails with attachement. Usually I would do this with R or SAS. Now, I have to look for another solution. Since I have access to internet I thought to use the web access ("Outlook web app") of our institution. I would like to do this with Perl since I have some experience (data processing, regular expression) but I have no idea how to access to internet. I did some research and found some modules:
Email::Folder::Exchange: only reading mails? (I didn't success to install)
WWW::Mechanize: only webbrowsing?
It would be very helpful if somebody could give some advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a web mail server **is** "only webbrowsing", so `WWW::Mechanize` might do the job.

You may find that you need support for JavaScript though (it is a web application so a dependancy on JS is not unlikely), in which case you will need a JavaScript aware backend such as `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`, `WWW::Selenium`, or `Wight`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have js. Thanks for the answer. I will try if I can manage the modules.